# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, sql

I get this erro: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\tennis\ronde2-wijziging.php:59`

```php
// code van het knop wijzigen
if(isset($_POST['wijzig'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $speler1  = $_POST['speler1'];
    $speler2  = $_POST['speler2'];
    $uitslag1 = $_POST['uitslag1'];
    $uitslag2 = $_POST['uitslag2'];
    $datum    = $_POST['datum'];
    $veld     = $_POST['veld'];

    //UPDATE: gegevens in de form wijzigen.
    $sql = "UPDATE ronde1 SET speler1 = :speler1, speler2 = :speler2, uitslag1 = :uitslag1,
    uitslag2= :uitslag2, datum= :datum, veld= :veld WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt = $pdoConnect->prepare($sql); //stuur naar mysql.
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id );
    $stmt->bindParam(":speler1", $speler1 );
    $stmt->bindParam(":speler1", $speler1 );
    $stmt->bindParam(":uitslag1", $uitslag1 );
    $stmt->bindParam(":uitslag2", $uitslag2 );
    $stmt->bindParam(":datum", $datum );
    $stmt->bindParam(":veld", $veld );
    $stmt->execute();

    // $_SESSION['message'] = "Speler is gewijzigd";
    // $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning";
    header("location: #.php");
    exit;
}
```

I want to update my data.**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution worked but didn't explain why it did go wrong in the first place. The user dpant explains in the comments why your code snippet was not working.

Credits go to him

dpant:

Most probably the problem with your original code was that you were binding the :speler1 parameter twice (the :speler2 parameter was never bound). This was just a typo in your code. Take a close look at it.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: I have tried it again but still doesn't work

Comment: You still get the same error?

Comment: yes, I get still the same error

Comment: I have changed my answer can you try this?

Comment: thank you very much, it works finally, but what did I wrong?

Comment: @imad Most probably the problem with your original code was that you were binding the `:speler1` parameter twice (the `:speler2` parameter was never bound). This was just a typo in your code. Take a close look at it.

Comment: @TotalNewbie No. The data parameter in execute is optional. The way OP was doing it would be fine too if not for the typo.

Comment: @dpant   is right You write  this line twice "$stmt->bindParam(":speler1", $speler1 );"

Comment: ah sorry didn't see that